# Jasper Report - Printing specific pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a master report having many customers and each customers may have different number of pages.  I would like to export to PDF only the customers having specific number of pages.

I was able to create a variable in page footer that will give number of pages each customer has but i am not able to export into PDF given a "page number"

Is this possible?  Experts please help.

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

In Jasper there is a property called **Print When Expression** I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Add the PrintWhenExpression as a boolean parameter to be given when compiling the report.

```
'<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{variable name})]]></printWhenExpression>'
```